# Disable warning only in one place

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml, flash-builder, compiler-warnings

In an MXML code

```
<fx:Script>
   public var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
</fx:Script>
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{data}" />
```

I'm getting a warning:

*Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to "data"*

I know that the data provider will be never changed in this case, and want to suppress this warning in this case, but I don't want to completely disable it, `-show-binding-options=false` in all project is not an option.

How to disable a warning only in one place? Disabling for the whole file is not so good, but acceptable.

Comment: No good answer so far.. Adding [Bindable] is overkill and not always possible.

Answer (score 2):

How about just making your `data` variable bindable? Something like:

```
<fx:Script>
   [Bindable]
   public var data:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
</fx:Script>
<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{data}" />
```

Comment: Interesting I just opened up a clean project with just the code you wrote above and the tried adding and removing the [Bindable] metadata tag. After adding it, the warning disappeared. Could you maybe post a larger snippet of the code?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `<fx:Script></fx:Script>` you could use `<fx:Declarations></fx:Declarations>`. Any object declared in that MXML element is bindable implicitly. Here's how your code will look like then:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <s:ArrayCollection id="data" />
</fx:Declarations>

<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{data}" />
```

Additionally it becomes much more readable and there's no mix of ActionScript and MXML. Because your collection is declared as public it makes difference whether to use ActionScript with `[Bindable]` or using MXML.

BTW, a general recommendation for cleaner code is to separate ActionScript completely from MXML. For instance in my projects I create a separate ActionScript file for each MXML component in the form `<NameOfComponent>Includes.as`.